# Is it possible to use @XmlHeader together with Jackson?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jackson, jax-rs

I'm marshalling my objects with Jackson (annotations) to JSON & XML and it works really great but there's a problem with XML.I want to add a DTD-File.I searched a little bit and found the @XmlHeader-Annotation (org.glassfish.jersey.message.XmlHeader) to add a header :

```
@Path("resources/xml/hashtagstatistic")
@GET
@XmlHeader("<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM \"test.dtd\">")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

public Database getStatisticAsXml(){
    return serviceController.getDatabase();
}
```

But it's not working. I tried the same with jaxb and there the header was added to my XML-Output.But I want to use Jackson because it returns easy my wanted structure (I don't like/want adapters). Is there a possibility to fix this or are there other solutions to handle this problem with the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's a Jersey specific annotation, so Jackson won't know anything about it. I see a couple options. You could use a [`WriterInterceptor`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9818), and just write the header yourself.

```
@Provider
public class XmlHeaderWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo info;

    @Override
    public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context)
                    throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        final OutputStream outputStream = context.getOutputStream();

        XmlHeader anno = info.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(XmlHeader.class);
        if (anno != null) {
            String value = anno.value();
            writeToStream(outputStream, value);
        }
        context.proceed();
    }
}
```

Or you could create a [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html). But instead of implementing your own from scratch, you could just extend [the one from Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/xml/JacksonXMLProvider.java) (assuming this is what you're currently using)

```
@Provider
public class MyJackonXmlProvier extends JacksonJaxbXMLProvider {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo info;

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object value, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
                        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
                        MultivaluedMap<String,Object> httpHeaders, 
                        OutputStream entityStream) {

        // do same thing as example above
        super.writeTo(pass, all, arguments)
}
```

Which ever one you use, just make sure to register it with the application.

Comment: Okay awesome! It worked for me :). I've never heard about WriterInterceptors before because I'm new to this topic. Is it correct to replace your writeToStream-Methode with a simple outputStream.write(value.getBytes()) ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah you could do that.