# How to add DOCTYPE in REST request body?

Tags: xml, web-services, jersey, dtd, doctype

I have to consume a web service using Jersey with application/xml content type.

I have dtd for it and generated POJOs.
However the request body needs to have something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE someService PUBLIC "-//Something//DTD Something SomeService v1//EN" 
  "http://dtd.something.com/someService_v1.dtd">
<customer>
  <name>Test</name>
  <age>20</age>
</customer>
```

The actual Customer POJO is very big and here only for getting some idea.

In request body I'm not able to get the -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE someService PUBLIC "-//Something//DTD Something SomeService v1//EN" 
  "http://dtd.something.com/someService_v1.dtd">
```

Any idea how to get it in Jersey request body?
I'm using Jersey v1.13.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do using WriterInterceptor.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38017202/5456372

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jax_rs_2_adding_http